# how to connect to Dell N1548P with ansible

Tags: switch, dell, ansible

I could not find ansible module specific to dell switches yet. Existing modules mostly refer to dell emc products.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Short version: the Ansible connection type you want is `ansible.netcommon.network_cli`

Longer version:

The N1548P's operating system, OS6, doesn't have a RESTAPI like OS10/SONiC. Subsequently, Ansible is effectively just acting as a passthrough to the CLI over SSH. The documentation for it is [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_dellos6.html). To quote the docs, the setup looks like this:

```
ansible_connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli
ansible_network_os: dellemc.os6.os6
ansible_user: myuser
ansible_password: !vault...
ansible_become: yes
ansible_become_method: enable
ansible_become_password: !vault...
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q bastion01"'
```

Obligatory legal note: I work for Dell.

Comment: "ansible_ssh_common_args" Do I need this? I have an inventory files seperating switches vendor by vendor. A simple ansible playbook would be helpful that I can develop further.

Comment: "https://github.com/ansible-collections/dellemc.os6" without this collection is it possible to run some status information like "show version"

Comment: Thanks Grant. I cannot see the N1548P's operating system is OS6 with commands like show version or show system. How can I verify if the N1548P's operating system is OS6